# How to combine outputs of multiple forecast::accuracy() results into table for comparison and plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, forecasting

I have called `forecast::accuracy()` on 4 pairs of time series, and the output of each of these is a 2x8 matrix of accuracy measurements.

```
> acc1
                        ME      RMSE       MAE      MPE     MAPE      MASE        
ACF1 Theil's U
Training set -3.918303e-05 0.5315159 0.3574662 86.62683 164.6431 0.6785569 
-0.00042333        NA
Test set      6.959079e-02 0.6452657 0.4388499 61.94763 105.3055 0.8330428  
0.45847534 0.9572293
```

I want to, in effect, `ggplot` the results of **only the RMSE column**, for **both rows**, for **each series**. This plot should probably include a distinct color for each series, and 2 point symbols corresponding to the train/test rows. But for that, I'll need to get this info a into a **tidy dataframe**.

What series of steps need to occur to get from these 4 matrices to a tidy dataframe? I already have `tidyverse` loaded but I'm open to base R too.

Reproducable data:

```
library(forecast)

x <- NULL
x$obs <- runif(3652)
x <- as.data.frame(df)
y <- NULL
y$obs <- runif(365)
y <- as.data.frame(df)

x1 <- ts(x$obs, start=c(2007, 10), end=c(2017, 9), frequency = 365)
y1 <- ts(y$obs, start=c(2016, 9), end=c(2017, 9), frequency = 365)
x2 <- ts(x$obs, start=c(2007, 10), end=c(2017, 9), frequency = 365)
y2 <- ts(y$obs, start=c(2016, 9), end=c(2017, 9), frequency = 365)
x3 <- ts(x$obs, start=c(2007, 10), end=c(2017, 9), frequency = 365)
y3 <- ts(y$obs, start=c(2016, 9), end=c(2017, 9), frequency = 365)
x4 <- ts(x$obs, start=c(2007, 10), end=c(2017, 9), frequency = 365)
y4 <- ts(y$obs, start=c(2016, 9), end=c(2017, 9), frequency = 365)

acc1 <- accuracy(x1,y1)
acc2 <- accuracy(x2,y2)
acc3 <- accuracy(x3,y3)
acc4 <- accuracy(x4,y4)
```

Comment: What are `x` & `y` in your code for reproducible data?

Comment: I've fixed the error in the reproducible data. X is a training set; Y is a testing set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**< Base R solution >**

I plotted RMSE of the training and test data, using different colors and different symbols.

```
acc1 = data.frame(matrix(data = 
c(-3.918303e-05, 0.5315159, 0.3574662, 86.62683, 164.6431, 0.6785569, -0.00042333, NA,
  6.959079e-02, 0.6452657, 0.4388499, 61.94763, 105.3055, 0.8330428, 0.45847534, 0.9572293), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE) )
rownames(acc1) = c("Training set", "Test set")      
colnames(acc1) = c("ME", "RMSE", "MAE", "MPE", "MAPE", "MASE", "ACF1", "Theil's U")      

acc2 = acc1 + 1
acc3 = acc1 + 2
acc4 = acc1 + 3

lsAcc = list(acc1, acc2, acc3, acc4)
dfAcc = do.call(what = rbind, args = lsAcc)
dfAcc$rowPair = ceiling(1:8 * 0.5)

plot(0, cex=0, xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,4))
points(x = dfAcc$rowPair[grepl(pattern = "Training", rownames(dfAcc))], 
       y = dfAcc$RMSE[   grepl(pattern = "Training", rownames(dfAcc))],
       pch = 2, col="blue")
points(x = dfAcc$rowPair[grepl(pattern = "Test", rownames(dfAcc))], 
       y = dfAcc$RMSE[   grepl(pattern = "Test", rownames(dfAcc))],
       pch = 3, col="red")
```

[image]

As. Z.Lin asked you, your code is not reproducible. You are missing to define the objects x and y.
I recreate a dataset using your partial data.

Comment: At first I had trouble implementing this, but then I realized that the first several lines are not only for the purpose of creating reproducible data, but essential for converting the matrices to data frames, assigning row names, etc. Answer given.

Comment: But how would you modify this plot to use a different color for each "acc" and show a legend? I feel this is essential.